# Background in safari is distorted

Tags: css, safari

I'm working on a new client's website, and everything looks good in every browser except safari. The Problem: The Background image is not responding to the css in place in safari(The 5px size).

```
.et_pb_section_0 {  /* The background CSS */
    background: url(http://www.elsyf-staging.com/esm/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/bg.png) 5px;
}
```

I have been unable to find any definitive information regarding this issue.

Because Safari shares webkit functionality with chrome, attempts to resolve this issue via that resulted in the site breaking in chrome. Is there a way to target safari specifically?

Comment: Looks like you got it solved on another site? Maybe you should mark this as done or delete

Comment: You have two unrelated issues; I only have an answer for the first. Would you mind moving the issue about small <img>s in the slider to a new question?

Comment: Sure thing, Editing now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CSS `background` shorthand property, the `background-position` comes before `background-size`. This makes your `5px` correspond to `background-position`, not `background-size`.

To fix this, add a `background-position` and separate it from `background-size` with a slash:

```
.et_pb_section_0 {
    background: url("http://www.elsyf-staging.com/esm/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/bg.png") 0 / 5px;
}
```

Alternatively, define `background-image` and `background-size` separately:

```
.et_pb_section_0 {
    background-image: url("http://www.elsyf-staging.com/esm/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/bg.png");
    background-size: 5px;
}
```

Comment: EDIT: Fixed by increasing the background size to 300px. odd how it behaves differently.

Comment: I used your answer to fix it, with the aformentioned change. Thanks for the help!

Comment: My pleasure! Glad you were able to fix it.